# Парсить во Fragment приложения для отображения в ListView

Tags: android, синтаксический-анализ, json

у меня есть json такого вида:

```
{"ID":null,"name":"Doe","first-name":"John","age":25,"hobbies":["reading","cinema",{"sports":["volley-ball","badminton"]}],"address":{}}
```

Каким образом я могу его парсить во Fragment приложения, для отображения в ListView?

Answer (score 1):

распарсить с помощью JSONArray и JSONObject, вывести в ListView с помощью любого удобного адаптера